# Error via paginating

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-paginator

Thrown next exception: Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "./opt/lampp/htdocs/guest-book/module/Records/view/records/records/paginator"; resolver could not resolve to a file. I've tried to set path different ways and in different directories, but still doesn't works

Controller:

```
class RecordsController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $recordsTable;
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $field = (string) $this->params()->fromRoute('field', 'date');
        $order = (string) $this->params()->fromRoute('order', 'desc');
        $array = array('records' =>$this->getRecordsTable()->getByOrder($field, $order),);
        $paginator = new Paginator\Paginator(new Paginator\Adapter\ArrayAdapter($array));
        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->params()->fromRoute('page', 1));
        $paginator->setPageRange(3);
        $paginator->setDefaultScrollingStyle('Sliding');
        print_r($paginator);
        $pag = new Helper\PaginationControl();
        $pag::setDefaultViewPartial('opt/lampp/htdocs/guest-book/module/Records/view/records/records/paginator.phtml', 'default');
        $vm = new ViewModel($array);
        $vm->setVariable('paginator', $paginator);
        return $vm;
    }
```

RecordsTable:

```
class RecordsTable
{
    protected $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function getByOrder($field, $order)
    {
        $this->field = $field;
        $this->order = $order;
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) {
        $select->order($this->field.' '.$this->order);        
        });
        return $resultSet;      
    }
```

In View:

```
<?php if (count($this->paginator)): ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($this->paginator as $item): ?>
```

or just:

```
<? echo $this->paginator;?>
```

Still a problem.

Thanks gratefully!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using a view helper inside the controller? git rid of that..

```
$pag = new Helper\PaginationControl();
$pag::setDefaultViewPartial('opt/lampp/htdocs/guest-book/module/Records/view/records/records/paginator.phtml', 'default');
```

Use it properly inside the template file:

```
<?php echo $this->paginationControl($paginatior, 'Sliding', 'records/records/paginator.phtml')  ?>
```